# Terminated due to memory issue while running the app on iPhone, works fine on the iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, memory

My application crashes when running on the iPhone but works fine when running on iPad.

I have a large son file which gets loaded first into my manager object and then gets loaded into a HTML file which the loads it onto a web view. I have many projects in my app and when I click on particular project the web view of that particular projects loads up.

All the other projects (Medium to large) work just fine but there is one project which has a large JSON value crashes when I click. But it works just fine on the iPad.

```
2017-11-27 17:10:39.097616+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 299} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.097751+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 299} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.097992+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 272} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.098141+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 221} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.098648+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 221} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.098792+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 318} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.098964+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 403} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.099175+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 272} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.099344+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 247} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.099428+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 181} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.099558+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 247} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.099872+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 272} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.100048+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 221} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.100428+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 221} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.100543+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 318} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.100908+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 403} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.101088+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 272} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.101250+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 247} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.101387+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 181} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.101496+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1199, 247} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.102609+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {3325, 100} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.102688+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1290, 138} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.102784+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1290, 151} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.103757+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {3325, 100} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.103889+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1290, 138} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
2017-11-27 17:10:39.104017+0900 beecanvas[12251:4095573] Warning: A DTAttributedLabel with size {1290, 151} is using a non-tiled layer. Set the layer class to a CATiledLayer subclass with [DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[DTTiledLayerWithoutFade class]].
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

Comment: Have you googled the multiple warnings which seem to be telling you exactly what is wrong and what to do to fix them? It seems like that would be a good first step.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand the problem from the info you have shared with us....
BTW, those warnings indicate that some action is performed multiple time until you ran out of memory. it suggests you need to handle memory warnings in your app

Comment: A quick google shows that you’re using DTCoreText which suggests your long label is not in a web view as html but is an actual label. And the developer of be framework says that for long text you should be using a CATiledLayer. https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/issues/1096

Comment: Could you tell me how can I assign that, by any chance ? I have a text Label of the DTAttributedLabel